# Impressionist and Chartkick

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, chartkick

I would like to display a simple bar chart of views against Posts. I'm using the [Impressionist](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist) gem to track the number of impressions on each Post, and I'm using the [Chartkick](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick) gem to create the bar chart.

This is the code I have in my view:

```
<%= bar_chart @posts.map{|post|
    {name: post.title, data: post.impressionist_count }
} %>
```

Both gems are working fine in other areas, and the above code passes without any errors, but what gets rendered is an *empty* bar chart with an accurate legend.

It seems like there should be a simple solution, but I can't find it!

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

`bar_chart @posts.map{|post| [post.title, post.impressionist_count] }`